# find all the points on the line $y = 1 - x$ which are $2$ units from $(1, -1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am really struggling with this one.  I'm teaching my self pre-calc out of a book and it isn't showing me how to do this.  I've been all over the internet and could only find a few examples.  I only know how to solve quadratic equations by converting them to vertex form and would like to stick with this method until it really sinks in.  What am I doing wrong?

1.) Distance formula $\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (-1 -1 + x)^2}=2$

2.) remove sqrt, $(x - 1)(x - 1) + (x - 2)(x - 2) = 4$

3.) multiply, $x^2 - 2x +1 + x^2 -4x +4 = 4$

4.) combine, $2x^2 -6x +5 = 4$

5.) general form, $2x^2 -6x +1$

6.) convert to vertex form (find the square), $2(x^2 - 3x + 1.5^2)-2(1.5)^2+1$

7.) Vertex form, $2(x-1.5)^2 -3.5$

8.) Solve for x, $x-1.5 = \pm\sqrt{1.75}$

9.) $x = 1.5 - 1.32$ and $x = 1.5 + 1.32$

10.) $x = 0.18$ and $2.82$

When I plug these two $x$ values back into the vertex form of the quadratic equation, I'm getting $y = 0.02$ for both $x$ values.  These points are not on the line.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Assuming that you’ve solved the quadratic equation correctly, plug the values that you got for $x$ into the equation of the *line*.

Comment: I did this but the points don't show up on the line.  This is why I know I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: In the last paragraph of your question you write that you plug these values back into the quadratic equation. (In which case, you’ve probably made some error since you should get zero.)

Comment: yes and then I get points (0.18, 0.02) and (2.82, 0.02) which are not on the line of y = 1 - x

Comment: If I understand your solution, you are finding $y$ from the quadratic $2x^2-6x+1=y$.  But the quadratic at step 5 is $2x^2-6x+1=0$ not $2x^2-6x+1=y$.

Comment: $1-0.18 \ne 0.02$. You’re clearly not plugging these values into the equation $y=1-x$ of the line.

Comment: well...maybe that is where I'm messing it up.  I'm plugging 0.18 back into the vertex form to find y.

Comment: @Key Flex.  Cool!  Ok, so I didn't mess that part up.  But what do you get when you solve for x using vertex form?  Is it the same as me?  If so, why doesn't this line up with the quadratic equation points?

Comment: @maybedave I got the correct answer when I solved for $x$ using the vertex form

Comment: @Key Flex,  Perfect!  Let me try again and figure out what the heck I did wrong.

Comment: @Key Flex, Actually, can you show me the steps you used?  Do you get what I did in step 8?

Comment: @maybedave See the edit in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from truncating the answers to only a few significant digits, which can throw things off, everything is fine up until the very last step when you try to compute the corresponding $y$-values. You find those by plugging the $x$-values that you’ve computed into the equation $y=1-x$ of the *line*. If you do that, you can’t help but get points that lie on the line, assuming of course that you’ve solved the quadratic equation correctly. Specifically, the two points on the line are $(0.18, 0.82)$ and $(2.82, -1.82)$ or, more precisely, $\left(\frac32+\frac{\sqrt7}2,-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt7}2\right)$ and $\left(\frac32-\frac{\sqrt7}2,-\frac12-\frac{\sqrt7}2\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

Another, possibly easier way to tackle this is to find the intersection points between a circle centered at $(1,-1)$ with radius $2$, and $y=1-x.$

The equation for the circle would be $$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=4$$ The equation of the line is $$y = 1-x$$

We can plug in $1-x$ for $y$ in the equation for the circle to get $$(x-1)^2+(2-x)^2=4$$
Expanding,
$$x^2-2x+1+4-4x+x^2=4$$
or
$$2x^2-6x+1=0$$
If you use the quadratic equation, you'll get $\frac32\pm\frac{\sqrt 7}2$. Plugging back into to either equation (preferably the linear equation), you'll get the coordinates as $(\frac32\pm\frac{\sqrt 7}2,-\frac12\pm\frac{\sqrt 7}2)$

Comment: This is exactly the same equation that the O.P. has in step 5 using an equivalent derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the general form $2x^2-6x+1=0$

Now solve for x,
$$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
$$x=\dfrac32\pm\dfrac12\sqrt{7},$$

Now try to plug in these values of $x$.

**Edit:**

$$2(x-1.5)^2-3.5=0$$
$$2(x^2+2.25-3x)=3.5$$
$$x^2-3x+2.25=1.75$$
$$x^2-3x+0.5=0$$
$$2x^2-6x+1=0$$

Comment: The O.P. already has this. The problem isn’t solving the derived quadratic equation, but rather what to do with these solution.

Comment: The $x$ values which the O.P found were wrong.

Comment: @Key Flex, yes, your values are what the book has.  I guess I should just be using the quadratic equation and not using the vertex form to solve them so I guess I messed it up somewhere in that form.

Comment: I was hoping someone could tell me what steps I did wrong though in the O.P.

Comment: The values are correct to the two decimal places used.

Comment: my values for x in the O.P are correct?  now i'm really confused :)

Comment: @maybedave your $x$ values are not correct

Comment: @maybedave It’s what I’ve already told you in my comments to the question: you’re computing the corresponding $y$-values incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks amd.  I think it is more than that.  The x values don't line up with the book answer.  The book answer matches what Key Flex did with the quadratic equation but I don't get them when using the vertex form to solve it.

Comment: @maybedave you got the vertex $2(x-1.5)^2-3.5$ which is absolutely correct. I think you did some calculation mistake in calculating for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$2x^2 - 6x + 1 = 0$

This looks good.

then I would say 
$x = \frac {3\pm\sqrt 7}{2}$ is simpler than $x = 1.5 \pm \sqrt {1.75}$

Plug each value of $x$ into $y = 1-x$ to find $y.$

$y = 1 - \frac {3+\sqrt 7}{2} = \frac {-1-\sqrt 7}{2}\\y = 1 - \frac {3-\sqrt 7}{2} = \frac {-1+\sqrt 7}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

After getting those two roots $ (x_1,x_2) $ we get next by plugging in $ (1-y)$ for $x$ a second quadratic in $y:$

$$ 2y^2+2y-3=0$$

which supplies corresponding roots

$$ (y_1,y_2)= \frac{-1\pm \sqrt7}{2}.$$